# "missing a template for this request format and variant." when trying to render AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use a select_tag here to filter a list of kanji words. 
My idea here is when user select options from dropdown -> auto submit form -> use AJAX to get to `search_by_lesson` action and fill data to #kanji_list. But I got 2 problem:

1. While I have `remote: true` in my `form_tag`, When i select from dropdown, browser still navigates to a new page `http://localhost:3000/search_kanjis_by_lesson?lesson=1` but not stays at index page.
2. The error in the title. While I want this `search_by_lesson` only render by ajax, I don't want to have a seperate `search_by_lesson.html.erb` in folders.

Here's my `index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag search_kanjis_by_lesson_path(lesson: params[:lesson]), method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= select_tag :lesson, options_for_select(@lessons), include_blank: true, onchange: "this.form.submit()" %>
<% end %>
<table class="ui celled padded striped table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Kanji</th>
            <th>Meaning</th>
            <th>Lesson</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="kanji_list">
        <%= render 'index' %>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I use a partial to render the list `_index.html.erb`

```
<% @kanjis.each do |kanji| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= kanji.word %></td>
        <td><%= kanji.meaning %></td>
        <td><%= kanji.lesson %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

I got this in my routes

```
resources :kanjis

get '/search_kanjis_by_lesson', to: 'kanjis#search_by_lesson', as: :search_kanjis_by_lesson
```

and in my kanjis_controllers.rb

```
class KanjisController < ApplicationController 

    # ... other generic actions: edit, show ...

    def index
        @kanjis = Kanji.all
        @lessons = [*1..32]     # @lessons is just an array of int.
    end

    def search_by_lesson
        @kanjis = Kanji.find_by_lesson params[:lesson]
    end
end
```

Finally, I have a search_by_lesson.js.erb

```
$("#kanji-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>")
```

Comment: Try adding respond_to block in your controller

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

In your index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_kanjis_by_lesson_path, method: :get, remote: true do %>
<%= select_tag :lesson, options_for_select(@lessons), include_blank: true %>
<% end %>
```

In your application.html.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#lesson').change(function(){
  $('form').submit();
 });
});
```

In your KanjisController

```
    def search_by_lesson
      @kanjis = Kanji.find_by_lesson params[:lesson]
      respond_to do |format|
       format.js
      end
    end
```

In your search_by_lesson.js.erb

```
$(".kanji_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index') %>")
```

Comment: Now i have another error: "ActionController::UnknownFormat" at line `respond_to do |format|`

Comment: also check in your log if request is being processed as js or html

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try that code it should work